# Authorize.net's getHostedPaymentPageRequest lineItems does not work

Tags: authorize.net

Ok. I have been looking for help with this and have not found any yet. I am using Authorize.net, and wanting to use their hosted payment web page. I set up XML data to post to them. I can get it to work when I don't use `<lineItems>`. I will get a token returned so I can have their form sent to my web page.

When I add `<lineItems`> I don't get any errors, but the token is not returned. I have found multiple sample codes and have tried them all with no success. The authorize.net documentation shows the tags as:

```
<lineItems>
  <lineItem>
    <itemID>1234</itemId>
    <name>ProductName</name>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    <unitPrice>25</unitPrice>
  </lineItem>
</lineItems>
```

I have sent Authorize.net an e-mail asking them for help, but I have not received any response.

I also have tried other configurations and attribute combinations and still nothing.

I really need to get this working so I can get my shopping cart up and running.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: Please show your whole request

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the error messages to show up and was finally able to get it to work. I was just not using the right letter case, "unitprice" instead of "unitPrice". Thanks for taking the time to look at this post.

Tony

Comment: Why did you create a new account to post this answer?